# Flexbox doesn't constrain an SVG element inside a div (but is okay with a SVG element alone)

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

I have an SVG constrained to 30% inside a flexbox:

```html
<body style="height: 100vh;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
    <svg style="flex-basis: 30%" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">      
      <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
    </svg>
    <div style="flex-basis: 70%; background-color: orange;">
      flex-basis: 70%
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But when I put that SVG inside a div constrained to 30% the SVG takes all the space:

```html
<body style="height: 100vh;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
    <div style="flex-basis: 30%;">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">      
        <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50"></ellipse>
      </svg>
    </div>    
    <div style="flex-basis: 70%; background-color: orange;">
      flex-basis: 70%
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I constrain the SVG to the parent `div`'s height in the second example?

(I've tried setting `style="height: 100%"` on the SVG in the second example as a shot in the dark but without success.)

Comment: min-height: 0; to the div of the SVG

Comment: `flex-basis: 30%` means take all available space, but minimally 30%, otherwise 'wrap' (when parent wrap is enable, otherwise 'overflow'). In the 2nd demo change `flex-basis` to `width` (or `max-width`) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @RenevanderLende. It appears I didn't understand what flex-basis meant.

Comment: And yes @TemaniAfif that works also. I've chosen to use 'width' instead.

Comment: @RenevanderLende flex-basis doesn't mean take all the available space. Flex-basis define the initial height to 30% but due to the default min-height constraint the final height is bigger. Also note that flex-grow is by default 0 so the element should not grow past 30%  https://jsfiddle.net/08nbkezv/

Comment: please don't add the answer inside the question. A question need to remain a quesiton

Comment: I tried to answer it, yet couldn't. I don't feel the linked answer really answers my question since my problem came from a misunderstanding of flex-basis.

Comment: the problem is not with flex-basis but a min-height issue like I said in my comment and the duplicate explain this very well. Using height is another alternative to achieve the same but it doesn't fix your actual issue.

Comment: @Temani Afif, I will need to revisit the W3C specs again, I guess. Thanks for the heads up...